# Why is my EF looking for a Plural table?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

When I originally ran my code, it was returning an Invalid object name 'dbo.SalesHeaders' error. The table it should have been looking for was dbo.SalesHeader. I was able to find the solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784064/entity-framework-throws-exception-invalid-object-name-dbo-basecs%20in%20particular) the third post with [this link](http://ardalis.com/Entity-Framework-Invalid-Object-Name-dbo.Albums), which adds `modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();`

My question is why did this happen in the first place? and How could I fix this without adding this line of code? As far as I can tell my other models and controllers are setup the same way and don't add a plural to the table.

**Context**

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using Infotech.Coverpools.Portal.Tintaglia.CodeFirst.Models.Mapping;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

namespace Infotech.Coverpools.Portal.Tintaglia.CodeFirst.Models
{
    public partial class TintagliaContext : DbContext
    {
        static TintagliaContext()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<TintagliaContext>(null);
        }

        public TintagliaContext()
            : base("Name=TintagliaContext")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Configuration> Configurations { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

        //New for Account Module
        public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<webpages_UsersInRoles> webpages_UsersInRole { get; set; }
        // public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

        public virtual DbSet<CustLedgerEntry> CustLedgerEntries { get; set; }

        public virtual DbSet<SalesHeader> SalesHeaders { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ConfigurationMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CustomerMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CustLedgerMap());
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>(); //line that fixed this//
        }
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Infotech.Coverpools.Portal.Tintaglia.CodeFirst.Models
{
    public class SalesHeader
    {
        public string CustomerNo_ { get; set; }
        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

        [Key]
        public string No_ { get; set; }

        public string DocumentType { get; set; }

        public string ExternalDocumentNo_ { get; set; }
        public DateTime ShipmentDate { get; set; }
        public string ShippingAgentCode { get; set; }

        public DateTime DatetoWebSales { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Infotech.Coverpools.Portal.Tintaglia.CodeFirst.Models;

namespace Infotech.Coverpools.Portal.Tintaglia.Web.Controllers
{
    public class SalesHeaderController : Controller
    {
        private TintagliaContext db = new TintagliaContext();

        //
        // GET: /SalesHeader/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<SalesHeader> ListSalesheaders;
            //using (TintagliaContext db = new TintagliaContext())
            {
                ListSalesheaders = db.SalesHeaders.ToList();
            }
            return View(ListSalesheaders);
            //return View(db.SalesHeaders.ToList());
        }
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<Infotech.Coverpools.Portal.Tintaglia.CodeFirst.Models.SalesHeader>
@using GridMvc.Html

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Open Orders";
}

<h2>Open Orders</h2>

<h2>Open Orders</h2>
<link href="~/Content/Gridmvc.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/gridmvc.js"></script>
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Add(m => m.CustomerNo_).Titled("Account Number").Filterable(true);
        columns.Add(m => m.OrderDate).Titled("Order Date").Filterable(true);
        columns.Add(m => m.No_).Titled("Order Number").Filterable(false);
    }).WithPaging(10).Sortable(true)
```

Comment: I just at the same problem - some 5 years later - and the options builder is not working in dotnet 7.  I have two contexts, one is working the other has this pluralization problem.