# Why I get exception when I try to fetch data from tables that has many to many relationship

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, ef-database-first

I use the EF6 database first identity 2.0 tables.
I try to get users and roles records and using navigation properties for this purpose.

This is my database scheme from VisualStudio:

[image]

This is my original database scheme from SQLManagmentStudio:

[image]

And here are entities:

```
    public virtual DbSet<ApplicationGroupRole> ApplicationGroupRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ApplicationGroup> ApplicationGroups { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ApplicationUserGroup> ApplicationUserGroups { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetRole> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserClaim> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserLogin> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUser> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
```

on this row:

```
var query = context.AspNetUsers.SelectMany(c=>c.AspNetRoles).ToList();
```

I get this error:

```
Invalid object name 'dbo.AspNetUserAspNetRoles'.
```

Any idea why I get this error?

Comment: Your AspNetRole table only has an id and name?  How is it linked to the user?

Comment: @NathanChampion AspNetRole.Id and ApplicationGroupRole.ApplicationRoleId are the same values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sounds like you are trying to get data from a table that does not exist in your database.
check to see if the table "dbo.AspNetUserAspNetRoles" exist in your database.

[This is a similar question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784064/entity-framework-throws-exception-invalid-object-name-dbo-basecs)

on second look at your question it look like you are trying to create a many to many relationship between AspNetUser and AspNetRoles
Create another POCO class the link the many to many relationship

```
public class AspNetUserAspnetRole{
public int AspNetRolesId {get;set;}
public int AspNetUserId {get;set;}
public AspNetRoles AspNetRoles {get;set;}
public AspNetUser AspNetUser {get;set;}

}
```

Add this class to the db context and add migration and update the database then your query should work

Comment: Thanks for the posted link, my solution is same as described in comment of the solution.