# ViewModel in ASP .net core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, controller

I'm trying to call my view model from controller but its giving me an error, SqlException: Invalid object name 'OfficerLangVM' when it reaches my `@foreach (var item in Model)` statement. I'm not too familiar with using view models, any help is appreciated.

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Privacy(string AgencyCity, string AgName, string AgGuid)
{

if (_Db.OfficerLangVMs == null)
{
    return Problem("Entity set 'FLIPV2Context.Officers'  is null.");
}
var officers = from o in _Db.OfficerLangVMs
               select o;
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(AgencyCity))
{
    officers = officers.Where(o => o.City!.Contains(AgencyCity));
}
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(AgName))
{
    officers = officers.Where(o => o.AgencyName!.Contains(AgName));
}

return View(officers);
}
```

View:

```html
@model IEnumerable<CoreApp.ViewModels.OfficerLangVM>
<!--Header-->
@{
    Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/PageHeader.cshtml");
}
<br />

<!--Administer Agency,FLAgSearch, FLSearchAgency-->
<head runat="server">
    <title>View Agency - Select Agency</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form asp-controller="Agency" asp-action="Privacy">
        <table style="margin-left:-250px" cellpadding="20" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" width="375" style="background-color:aliceblue">
                    <font face="Arial">
                        Enter Part of Agency Name:
                    </font>
                    <br />
                    <input type="text" name="AgName" width="250"/>
                    <br />
                    <font>
                        Or Enter City:
                    </font>
                    <br />
                    <input type="text" name="AgencyCity" maxlength="40" width="250"/>
                    <br />
                    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>

<br />
<tbody>
    <table class="table table-boardered table-striped" style="margin-left:-250px; background-color:lightgrey; width:100%" cellpadding="5">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AgencyName)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.City)</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AgencyName)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)</td>
                    <td>

                        <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.OfficerKey">Edit Officers</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }

    </table>
</tbody>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class OfficerLangVM
{

public List<Language> Language;
public Officer Officers;
public string OfficerKey;
public string LanguageKey; 
public string LanguageName;

[Display(Name = "Rank")]
public string OfficerRank;

[Display(Name ="Officer")]
public string FirstName;
public string LastName;

public string Fluency;

[Display(Name ="Agency")]
public string AgencyName;

[Display(Name ="Address")]
public string Address1;
public string City;

[Display(Name ="Zip Code")]
public string PostalCode;

public string State;
public string Phone;
public string Cell;
public string Ext;
public string Country;
public string Email;

[Display(Name ="Can Read")]
public string CanRead;

[Display(Name = "Can Write")]
public string CanWrite;

[Display(Name = "Can Speak")]
public string CanSpeak;

[Display(Name = "Can Understand")]
public string CanUnderstand;

[Display(Name ="Date Modified")]
public DateTime DateUpdated; 
 }
```

Comment: Are you using EFCore?

Comment: Yes, I'm connected to a database. OfficerLangVM is not a table in the database so that might be my problem.

Comment: you're returning officers, where your view is expecting the whole view model of OfficerLangVM.

Comment: I corrected it but it gives the same error.

Comment: `Invalid object name 'OfficerLangVM'` tells you that there's isn't a table *or* view called `OfficerLangVM` in your database.   If you do have a DB view that combines officer and lang into the structure of your model (class) then it's not called `OfficerLangVM` - you can tell EFcore what the view's called by adding eg `[Table("vwOfficerLang")]` to point to the actual (database) view.

Comment: Note: in asp.net-mvc terms, a "view model" is used for the UI view (.cshtml / partial / etc) - it is not a reference to a *database view* (which appears to be how you're using it here, but I may be mistaken).  The database view (or table) would just be "the model".  view(db) -> model -> viewmodel -> view(UI)  (yes, it's confusing)

Answer (score 1):

You defined the model in the View as `@model IEnumerable<CoreApp.ViewModels.OfficerLangVM>`, so the `officers` you send into the View `return View(officers);` must be an `IEnumerable<OfficerLangVM>`.

I mean I deduce you defined the variable `officers` in your controller similar to `public IEnumerable<OfficerLangVM> officers` or `public List<OfficerLangVM> officers`, otherwise you will get exception like below:

[image]

In the meantime, you mentioned `SqlException: Invalid object name 'OfficerLangVM' when it reaches my @foreach (var item in Model) statement` so that the issue should relate to how you query your data table.

This exception normally happened when we don't have a table which named as `OfficerLangVM` in the database. Here's a [high voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17437916) which sharing the same exception.

In your scenario, I'm afraid that you are trying to query the officers along with the language skill by city name and agency name, so that you might want to query the officer table instead of a `OfficerLangVM` table. It depends how you design your table to have the right code. What we can share here is that, if the View you are having now is exactly what you want, then you are required to return a list of `OfficerLangVM`, and the data content in `List<OfficerLangVM>` might require you to query several tables, or creating a Database View if required. If we had a officer table in database, then `var officers = from o in _Db.Officer select o;` will give us `IEnumerable<Officer>` as the response.

Here's my test:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebAppMvc2.Models.OfficerLangVM>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Privacy Policy";
}
<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<table class="table table-boardered table-striped" style="background-color:lightgrey; width:100%" cellpadding="5">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AgencyName)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.City)</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AgencyName)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)</td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.OfficerKey">Edit Officers</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

public IActionResult Privacy()
{
    var res = new List<OfficerLangVM> { 
        new OfficerLangVM{
            AgencyName = "agency A",
            City = "city A",
            OfficerKey = "key1"
        },
        new OfficerLangVM{
            AgencyName = "agency B",
            City = "city A",
            OfficerKey = "key2"
        }
    };
    return View(res);
}

namespace WebAppMvc2.Models
{
    public class OfficerLangVM
    {
        public Officer Officers;
        public string OfficerKey;
        [Display(Name = "name of Agency")]
        public string AgencyName;
        [Display(Name = "name of city")]
        public string City;
    }

    public class Officer {
        public int age { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image]